# Trouble with indeterminate form in integration by parts

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I'm in the middle of solving for the expectation value of $x^{2}$ and am having trouble with this integral:

> $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2}e^{-2k|x|} dx$

First, I recognized that the function is even so I changed the integral to

> $2 \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{2}e^{-2kx} dx$

And then I attempted to do integration by parts. My set up was as follows:

- $ u = x^{2} $ so that $du = 2xdx$
- $dv = e^{-2kx}$ so that $v = \frac{1}{-2k} e^{-2kx}$
- $2\cdot[x^{2}\frac{1}{-2k} e^{-2kx} |_{0}^{\infty} - 2 \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-2kx}dx]$

I'm finding trouble in evaluating the first term where I end u getting $(\infty \cdot 0) - (0 \cdot \frac{1}{-2k})$. I know the first term is an indeterminate form but I don't remember using L'hopitals rule to deal with it. As well, I think L'hopitals rule was only ever applied when getting indeterminate forms in the context of limits, not endpoint evaluations.

As well, I would have to do integration by parts again for the second term and get the same problem except just with $x$ instead of $x^2$

---

Im following along with a solutions manual and the answer is $\frac{2}{(2k)^{3}}$ The solutions manual does not really have worked solutions, just answers. Am I missing some trick here? Should I not be doing integration by parts to solve this integral?

Comment: $$\lim_{x \to +\infty} x^2 e^{-2 k x} = 0$$

Comment: An $\infty$ limit really means substitute R and let R tend to $\infty$. The limits you get are both $0$.

Comment: If you differentiate $x^n e^{-ax}$ you can work out a recursive equation for the integral $\int x^n e^{-ax} dx$ where you can express it through $\int x^{n-1}e^{-ax} dx$. I.e., there are explicit formulae for indefinite integrals $\int x^n e^{-ax} dx$ which you can use.